# How to use Get account/settings in twitter API?

Tags: api, twitter

How to use Get account/settings in twitter API, don't like other functions, there are no parameters(such as screen_name) for this function,and how to spectify the user and return the spectify account settings?

[Get account/settings in twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/settings)

Answer (score 0):

The request is implicitly for the authenticated user.

```
Requires authentication?    Yes (user context only)
```

So it isn't needed to provide parameters as you can only call this as yourself.  Provided you are correctly [signing requests](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/authorizing-requests) it should *just* work.